# Finiteness of integral closure.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$  be an algebraic variety and $x\in X$ . Why the normalization of the ring  $R=: \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is finite as $R$-algebra?

Comment: This is an application of Noether normalization. You'll find the proof in most commutative algebra books, for example in chapter 13 of Eisenbud.

Comment: Thanks. I will see the Eisenbud book.